# anchor tag download attribute is not working in cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am using cordova for android

```
 <a href="new.pdf" download>new</a>
```

its working in browser, but its not working in android device.
Please some one help me with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android version that attribute is a bit of "unknown". I got the following picture:

[image: browser compatibility of anchor attributes]

from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

**UPDATE:**

See the updated image and please pay attention to underlined platform names.

[image: Various browser compatibility for MOBILE (including Android) platforms for anchor tag]

Comment: how can i download the pdf file from anchor tag download attribute, is it possible.

Comment: Just look at the table above: It is not possible for Safari on IOS. As far as I can see, it is all shady (unknown) for Android. So, I would suggest you to look for other options.

Comment: I think you dint understand my question, i am using for android app, not android web browser

Comment: I think you did NOT understand the table above. Pay attention to tabs: first tab is for desktop browsers, second tab is for mobile. On the second tab (which is shown above) are listed various web browsers on different mobile platforms, including ANDROID, which is what you are having an issue with. I will add a new image to make it clearER for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot.....
Now i am clear about this. I came with another solution using plugins.

Comment: Just for helping  others and complete this thread, I suggest you to elaborate on the alternative solution you came up with for this problem. It may help, in the future, to those with the same problem. Cheers.

Comment: Sure, I came up with a plugin called cordovafiletransfer, and its documentation is available in the below link
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/